# Python Boost undefined symbol while using boost::noncopyable

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

I have issues while binding code using boost and python3.8

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boost-bindings/python_valve_controller.py", line 3, in <module>
    import python_valve_controller
ImportError: /app/boost-bindings/python_valve_controller.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI18ArmouredValveCntrl
```

**Module file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArmouredValveCntrl.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_valve_controller)
{
    class_<ArmouredValveCntrl, boost::noncopyable>("ArmouredValveCntrl")
        .def("coco_start", &ArmouredValveCntrl::coco_start)
    ;
};
```

**ArmouredValveCntrl.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "coco/runtime.h"

#include "Armour.h"
#include "PArmour.h"
#include "TestValveCntrl.h"

class ArmouredValveCntrl : public coco::BaseMultiThreadedEncapsulatingComponent {
 public:
  ArmouredValveCntrl();

  ~ArmouredValveCntrl();

  void coco_start() override;
  PArmourProvided &client() { return *client_; }
  void set_logger_recursively(coco::StateMachineLogger *logger) override;

 private:
  Armour armour_;
  SimulateValveCntrl testValve_;
  PArmourProvided *client_;
};
```

I need to use boost::noncopyable, otherwise I will get deleted a bunch of deleted errors like:

```
/usr/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp:133:13: error: use of deleted function 'ArmouredValveCntrl::ArmouredValveCntrl(const ArmouredValveCntrl&)'
  133 |             BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1ST(N, BOOST_PYTHON_UNFORWARD_LOCAL, nil)
      |             ^
In file included from /app/boost-bindings/python_valve_controller.cpp:5:
```

Is using boost::noncopyable the good approach? In that case, how do I fix the undefined symbol?

If not, how do I fix all the deleted errors (Ref: [Use of deleted function with boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122332/use-of-deleted-function-with-boostbind))?

Comment: Just for the sake of others, which Boost version are you using?

Comment: I tried using both 1.75 (installed manually) and also using the last Ubuntu version (I think its 1.73).